# Array of Obects with 2 dimensional array property error

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, for-loop

Asking here is a last resort, I have spent more than 50 hours on this one error, if anyone could lend me a hand I would greatly appreciate it.

Error: "Decunstructing Assignments are not supported by the current version of Javascript", "Expecting a semicolumn or newline".

Goal: Assign user input in a for loop to variables, use those variables to initialize object properties for each element of the object array.

```
function STUDENT(name, id, course, mark, sum)
    {
        this.studName = name;
        this.studentID = id;
        this.courses = course;
        this.marks = mark; //Attempted new array and marks[courses][0]
        this.studsum = sum;
    }

var student = new Array(30);

for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
       var name1 = prompt("Enter Student Name:");
        if (name1 !== "!!!")

            {
                var id1 = parseInt(prompt("input the students ID:", ""));

                for (var l = 0; l < course.length; l++)
                {
                    mark1[l] = parseFloat(validateMark(l));
                    sum1 += mark1[l];
                    coursesum[l] = mark1[l] + coursesum[l];
                }

                var student[i] = new STUDENT(name1, id1, course1, mark1, sum1);
                /*ERROR IS HERE ^*/


            }

    else
        i = 30; /*Breaks out of loop*/
    }/* end of for loop*/
```

I have tried many different things but this is the base of my code, all other functions are fine, console.log() for each variable works fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no `course` array. Also you should `var` your loop variables. Also it should be `student[i]` not `var student[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var student[i] = new STUDENT(name1, id1, course1, mark1, sum1);
```

into:

```
student[i] = new STUDENT(name1, id1, course1, mark1, sum1);
```

your array is already declared no need for a "var" infront of it.

PS: course in your loop is also undefined (in your current code).

Comment: It was without var before, right now the variables are all over the place, I have made so many changes I lost  track of what is happening, but i keep getting errors, if not here then somewhere else concerning this snippet, or a property of an object. Here its undefined but even when it was defined and working properly, I would put console.log() it would return the correct value, then would tell me it is NaN(used parseInt, log returned float) or undefined.